# Q: Let $X$ be a continous random variable s.t. $X\sim U(-1,3)$. Find $F_Y$, for $Y=X^4$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Q: Let $X$ be a continous random variable s.t. $X\sim U(-1,3)$. Find $F_Y$, for $Y=X^4$.

My attempts so far:

$F_Y(t)=P(Y\le t)=P(X^4\le t)=P(-\sqrt[4]{t}\le X\le\sqrt[4]{t})=F_X(\sqrt[4]{t})-F_X(-\sqrt[4]{t})$.

Since $X\sim U(-1,3)$
then $F_X(t)=\begin{cases}0&,  t<-1 \\ \frac{t+1}{4}&,  -1\le t\le 3 \\ 1&, 3<t &\end{cases}$

What I don't understand is how find the right way to split $F_Y(t)=F_X(\sqrt[4]{t})-F_X(-\sqrt[4]{t})$.

Comment: I think your doing fine just keep going !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075832/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go on first observe that $Y$ support is $y \in [0;3^4]$

Do a drawing of the transformation function

[image]

and observe that where $y \in [0;1]$ the transformation is not monotonic and thus

$$F_Y(y)=F_X[\sqrt[4]{y}]-F_X[-\sqrt[4]{y}]=\frac{\sqrt[4]{y}}{2}$$

In the other part of the support, the transformation is monotonic thus

$$F_Y(y)=F_X[\sqrt[4]{y}]=\frac{\sqrt[4]{y}+1}{4}$$

Concluding...

$$  F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y<0$ } \\
\frac{\sqrt[4]{y}}{2},  & \text{if $0 \leq y<1$ } \\
\frac{\sqrt[4]{y}+1}{4},  & \text{if $1 \leq y<3^4$ } \\
1,  & \text{if $ y\geq 3^4$ }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't understand why you used the monotone to determine to break the interval of range of $Y$. Why not break it by $[-1,0)$ and $[0,3]$, where two intervals are both monotonic?

Comment: @Tan because $[-1;0)$ and $[0;1]$ both map into $S_Y \in [0;1]$. See my drawing as an explanation

Answer (score 2):

Let's step back for a minute and think about what happens to $Y$ for various values of $X$.

When $-1 \le X \le 1$, then $0 \le Y \le 1$.  So when we pick some $y$ between $0$ and $1$, $$\Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[-y^{1/4} \le X \le y^{1/4}].$$  But when $1 < y \le 3^4$, instead of writing $-y^{1/4} \le X \le y^{1/4}$, the left-hand side inequality stops at $-1$ because that's where the support of $X$ ends.  And when $y > 81$, then both left and right sides of the inequality becomes $-1 \le X \le 3$.  So in summary we have $$\Pr[Y \le y] = \begin{cases} 0, & y < 0 \\
\Pr[-y^{1/4} \le X \le y^{1/4}], & 0 \le y \le 1 \\
\Pr[-1 \le X \le y^{1/4}], & 1 < y \le 81 \\
1, & y > 81. \end{cases}$$  Now there are no further restrictions and we can proceed with the evaluation of each case.

Comment: I think there are a couple of typos in your $Y$ support

Comment: @heropup , I understand the path you took, I just don't understand the way you broke down the intervals. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Benny I added a drawing of the problem in my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I finally got it :)