# $X\sim U(-1,3)$, and $Y\sim X^4$. How to find the p.d.f of $Y$ using transformation of variable?

Tags: probability, self-learning, density-function, change-of-variable

$X\sim U(-1,3)$, and $Y\sim X^4$. How to find the p.d.f of $Y$ using transformation of variable?

This is not a duplicated question of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997020/q-let-x-be-a-continous-random-variable-s-t-x-sim-u-1-3-find-f-y-for). I would like to know how to use transformation of variable method to step-by-step derive the p.d.f of $Y$.

For transformation of variable method, I mean $$f_Y(y) = f_X(x(y))|\frac{dx}{dy}|$$

Here is what I have attempted.

Since $Y=X^4$, we have

$$X=\begin{cases}-Y^{\frac{1}{4}}&,  X\in[-1,0) \\ Y^{\frac{1}{4}}&,  X\in[0,3] \end{cases}$$

Then  $$|\frac{dx}{dy}|=\frac{1}{4}y^{-\frac{3}{4}}$$

Also since $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{-1\leq X<0}+\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{0\leq X\leq3}$, we have $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{-1\leq -Y^{\frac{1}{4}}<0}|\frac{dx}{dy}| + \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{0\leq Y^{\frac{1}{4}}\leq3}|\frac{dx}{dy}|,$$
which means

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{8}y^{-\frac{3}{4}}\mathbb{1}_{0\leq Y\leq1} + \frac{1}{16}y^{-\frac{3}{4}}\mathbb{1}_{1\leq Y\leq3^4}$$

However, I don't think this is correct, and I don't know which step I made mistake. How to use transformation of variable method to step-by-step derive the p.d.f of $Y$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Q: Let $X$ be a continous random variable s.t. $X\sim U(-1,3)$. Find $F_Y$, for $Y=X^4$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997020/q-let-x-be-a-continous-random-variable-s-t-x-sim-u-1-3-find-f-y-for)

Comment: @Daman, thanks for your help but no. It is mysterious how they break range of $Y$ to the intervals. I would like to know change-of-variable formula help us to determine the intervals of the range of $Y$.

Comment: $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{8}y^{-\frac{3}{4}}\mathbb{1}_{0\leq y\leq1} + \frac{1}{16}y^{-\frac{3}{4}}\mathbb{1}_{1\leq y\leq3^4}$ looks correct.